# Echoing from a multidimensional array that contains an object

Tags: php, arrays, oop, multidimensional-array

Please don't shoot the noob. I've done a fair amount of research before asking this.  I have an array that is being returned that looks like this:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#7 (4) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["camp_name"]=>
    string(11) "Refuel Camp"
    ["director_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["camp_logo"]=>
    string(23) "images/Refuel_Camp3.jpg"
  }
}
```

Now do I echo out the "camp_name" so it displays "Refuel Camp"?

When I try to echo that value as

```
<?=  $camps["camp_name"];  ?>
```

I get Undefined index: camp_name

When I do

```
<?=  $camps->camp_name; ?>
```

I get  Trying to get property of non-object

I don't understand how to get to the inner part of that array.

Comment: The examples show the array having...   object(stdClass)#1 (1) {
    ["property"]=>
    array(3) {  
I don't have anything like "property" I can grab on to.  I just go from the object straight into the array.

Comment: Yes you have. **[0]=> Object...**  It's just a number and not a string.

Comment: Perfect! So $camps[0]->camp_name;

Comment: Exactly. You got it :)

Comment: The 0 obviously threw me off and I couldn't figure out the syntax. Tanks for your help, Rizier123!